# Problema com aspas no JSON

Tags: json

Estou rodando uma aplicação que lê um resultado em JSON.
Recentemente alterei meu servidor e notei que a aplicação parou de funcionar. Após vários testes descobri que o meu servidor novo colocou aspas em alguns valores, incapacitando a aplicação.

Para ilustrar, tenho os dois resultados em JSON, um que funciona e outro não:

> JSON - Funciona na aplicação
>   [{"id":1,"start":"1413972000000","end":"1413979200000","title":"9,10,11,12","agendamento_status":1,"userId":1,"nome":"Teste"}]

contra:

> JSON - Não funciona na aplicação
>   [{"id":"1","start":"1413972000000","end":"1413979200000","title":"9,10,11,12","agendamento_status":"1","userId":"1","nome":"Teste"}]

Notei que a diferença se dá apenas por conta da aspas.
Existe alguma forma de padronizar isso?

Comment: Como você está gerando o JSON? De fato, números literais são válidos, as aspas em torno deles são desnecessárias.

Comment: Que linguagem está a utilizar e em que código? Ambos os exemplos que colocou são válidos: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Estou utilizando o Laravel para gerar o Json. O estranho é que em um servidor ele gera com as aspas e em outro ele gera sem aspas.
O comando para gerar o JSON é o mesmo. Como descrito aqui: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema instalando o php-mysqlnd:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Como a instalação de um driver para mysql resolveu um problema com geração de JSON?!

Comment: Acho que o problema não está no seu json mas sim no modo que utiliza as variáveis enviadas pelo objeto em sua aplicação.